how to close gap between to edges when using bevel in edit mode?
Is there a way to make the edges snap to each other when using bevel in edit mode?



Hello it's not clear what's happening, could you please show some other pictures or share your file?

It would help, I think, if you showed us  before-bevel and after-bevel  pictures, so we can see what's going on. I'm having a tough time reproducing this topology

to add to 3fingeredfrog's answer, don't forget to select all and press M > Merge by Distance afterwards

Thanks moodboots, I have edited my answer to include your advice.

There is a way to prevent the edges from overlapping, maybe this will work for you?
In the Bevel last operator panel (bottom left hand corner of the 3D viewport) enable the Clamp Overlap option.

Once enabled for the first object it will remain enabled for any future bevelling.

As mentioned in the comments by moodboots, after bevelling remove any overlapping vertices, Select all > M to open the Merge menu and choose the merge By Distance option.
